# JAVA_OPTS for increasing heap size

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, jvm, heap-memory

I want to increase my Heap size. How can I use JAVA_OPTS for doing so.I am getting the following error may be this is because of low heap size

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3209)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:215)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:430)
    at com.android.dx.rop.type.Prototype.withFirstParameter(Prototype.java:370)
    at com.android.dx.rop.code.Rops.ropFor(Rops.java:1210)
    at com.android.dx.cf.code.RopperMachine.run(RopperMachine.java:478)
    at com.android.dx.cf.code.Simulator$SimVisitor.visitConstant(Simulator.java:692)
    at com.android.dx.cf.code.BytecodeArray.parseInstruction(BytecodeArray.java:763)
    at com.android.dx.cf.code.Simulator.simulate(Simulator.java:95)
    at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.processBlock(Ropper.java:684)
    at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.doit(Ropper.java:639)
    at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.convert(Ropper.java:252)
    at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:256)
```

Comment: @AmitBhargava yes after reading i asked this question. I am building code on command line. so I want to set this variable globally Do you know how to set this in enviroment(exports).

Comment: Not sure how to do this in Android, but in normal java you can set these options while using the 'java' command.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You should be able to use the information found in [this post](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/other-forums/development/programming-scripting/392905-java_opts.html).

```
-Xmszzzm
```

where zzz is your minimum size.

```
-Xmxzzzm
```

where zzz is your maximum size.

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms128m -Xmx512m"
```

You can find more info on VM args [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html).

How to set it globally in your environment depends on your operating system.  Which OS are you using?

**EDIT**:  I see the "ubuntu" tag now.

You should just be able to put the JAVA_OPTs line in `etc/environment`. Once you modify `etc/environment`, you'll have to log out and back in for the updated environment variables to take effect.

Comment: Is there a full form of OPTs? I mean is it simply shortened form of 'OPtional parameTers' or anything else?
We need to set several OPTs like for Maven and Catalina, we opts set for them also. I know the purpose. I just want to know it's full form. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say it's just shorthand for "options."

Comment: Fine. 'OPTs' looks cool for 'Options'. Thanks Jon once again. :)