# How to enable JSR 292 in JVM

Tags: java, netbeans, jvm, hotswap, jsr

I've added Hotswap agent to netbeans and while debugging I've seen the message:

> Dynamic Code Evolution Server VM warning: JSR 292 is disabled in this JVM.  Use -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+EnableInvokeDynamic to enable.

I've added the options to netbeans.conf.

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -J-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -J-XX:+EnableInvokeDynamic"
```

But the message is still showing in tomcat console.

Comment: Are you trying to debug netbeans or an application started from netbeans (http://stackoverflow.com/a/18723259 I think)?

Comment: I'm dubugging a maven project.

Comment: So, the jvm options for netbeans itself (which you're currently setting) are the wrong ones and you need to change how the maven projects gets executed. https://netbeans.org/kb/74/java/project-setup.html#deploy-jvm sounds about right but I'm not a netbeans user and maybe it's even different for maven projects.

Comment: @zapl there are no VM Options field in my case

Comment: There is always a way to set the options for a program you are running. However each program need it's own options unless you set an environment variable like JAVA_OPTS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003459/java-opts-for-increasing-heap-size